# Resource registered by this uri is not recognized

Tags: java, android-studio, uri

I have a problem with my android studio.
I have android studio 3.0.1 on mac and I'm having a problem with the URI

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.yuval.myapplication.MainActivity">
```

In the program, all the http are red and the error says "Resource registered by this uri is not recognized"

This error follows in all the projects I try to start.

I've looked in all the questions regarding this but nothing helps me.

Would appreciate any help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think your AndroidManifest.xml is missing these two lines:

```
`
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0"
`
```

The first five lines of AndroidManifest.xml that work OK are:

```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     package="com.example.petr.myfirstapp"
>     android:versionCode="1"
>     android:versionName="1.0"
```